# How to prepare floor for vinyl plank installation over old sheet vinyl

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring

I've demoed a built in bathroom vanity leaving a footprint that I had to fill in with OSB. The thickness of the new OSB and old sheet vinyl appears pretty darn level; maybe 1/16" (or less) off? Looking at the best options to 1) cover the seams where old vinyl meets OSB, but also 2) ensure that this new OSB replacement is level with the existing floor as best as possible? I'm not sure if a self-leveling compound can be poured on, or some form of floor patch could be troweled on to ensure a proper foundation before laying planks, or if this would even be overkill? Suggestions? For context, I'm installing 6 x 24" vinyl plank tiles over this. Separately, I also utilized screws (countersunk) to fasten the OSB to the previous subfloor which in hindsight apparently wasn't appropriate to do?

[image]

[image]

Is it Ok to use Henry’s patch’n level compound on the OSB and seams? Figured I could trowel it on and then sand presumably?

Unfortunately I don’t have the luxury of adding a thin underlayment to the entire room as the flooring that meets this room is so uneven and already low. Anymore depth added would make the transition very high and strange.

Comment: 1/16" isn't much difference, but a sharp transition of that much is likely to be a problem.  The transition is also in two directions, which could be an additional problem.  It looks from the second picture like it is the OSB that's lower.  I would use a filler to make everything level, or at least make the transition more gradual.

Comment: if that seam moves it could crack the covering

Answer (score -1):

I would use the Henrys or remove the sheet vinyl.    No problem with your countersunk screwheads.